# Render README Snippet from Relative Link

Tags: github, code-snippets, permalinks, github-flavored-markdown, relative-url

## Background

I am creating the `README.md` for my GitHub repo ("**MyRepo**"), which provides certain VBA functionality.  Here I wish to display a code snippet, which the user should paste into their own code.

Since this snippet enables the functionality, it is a crucial element of the project.  As such, I maintain it modularly in `src/Snippet.bas`.

## Goal

I am wish to combine the following features for the snippet in my `README`:

1. The button [image: 1] to copy the snippet with a single click.
2. The scrollable pane, which keeps the `README` visually uncluttered by the large snippet.
   [image: 2]
3. The injection of code from an upstream *source* file.
4. The dynamic injection of the *latest* code from that file.
5. The relative reference (`src/Snippet.bas`) to that file, rather than the unwieldy absolute (`https://github.com/Greg/MyRepo/tree/HEAD/src/Snippet.bas`).
6. The inclusion of the *entire* file, rather than a fixed section of it (`#L14-L22`).

## Issue

Unfortunately, **(1)** appears only for code samples written *manually* within ```` ``` ```` fences; and not for permalinks to the code.  As for **(2)**, it appears only for the permalinks; and not for the manually written samples.

While permalinks *do* achieve **(3)**, they seem anchored to a specific commit, and thus fail at **(4)**.  Furthermore, it seems they require the absolute URL, and do *not* render the relative for **(5)**.  Finally, they are anchored rigidly lines (`#L14-L22`) within the file, and thus do *not* accommodate **(6)**.

## Question

Is there a way to achieve all (or more) of these features in GitHub Flavored Markdown, or in the HTML it permits?  Or would this task require sophisticated GitHub Actions?

Alternatively, is there a URL parameter like `copy`, which automatically copies the linked file to the clipboard?

```
src/Snippet.bas?copy=1
```

Comment: I don't think GitHub supports general purpose includes, since they're typically a security problem.  In addition, copy and paste in web pages is either controlled by the browser or by JavaScript, and when using JavaScript it always has to be user-initiated, so it's impossible to copy to the clipboard just by using a URL.

Comment: @bk2204 Good to know!  In that case, what is best practice for embedding in my `README` the snippet of code maintained in my `src/Snippet.bas`?  Are GitHub Actions my only option?

Comment: I'd say that you probably just want to link to the code or the raw version of the file.  GitHub READMEs are not designed for general-purpose document formatting; if you need that, you need a website (say, GitHub Pages).

Comment: Gotcha.  I think I'll just link to the regular version of the file, which has the copy button for ease of use.